# How to connect a ClojureScript node REPL to my :node-library shadow-cljs project?

Tags: node.js, clojurescript, shadow-cljs, vscode-calva

**Context**

I am building a Node.js library with ClojureScript and [shadow-cljs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52894430/1244884). 
All development is done with ClojureScript but the build artefact is a NPM package. Example:

```clj
(ns com.example.answer)

(defn answer [] 42)
```

*build... release... then*

```
const answer = require('answer');
answer(); //=> 42
```

*NB: I recently contributed the details of my build setup to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52894430/1244884).*

My entire development environment is in a Docker container and I am using the "Visual Studio Code Remote - Container" extension.

- ClojureScript v1.10
- Node.js v12
- [shadow-cljs](http://shadow-cljs.org/) v2.8.55
- Visual Studio Code [Calva](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=betterthantomorrow.calva) extension (running in a [VS Code remote container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers))

**The "Problem"**

My build setup works fine (at least I think so!) but I'd like to implement a faster development feedback cycle.
In other words: I don't want to rebuild an entire NPM package just to test a few lines of change.

**The Perfect World** *aka "the question"*

In a perfect world I should be able to have a REPL open and be able to evaluate my ClojureScript code at all time.

No matter how I try to get there I seem to be blocked by the same underlying problem:

> No application has connected to the REPL server. Make sure your JS environment has loaded your compiled ClojureScript code.

**What I tried**

1. With `shadow-cljs` only:

   Given the following `shadow-cljs.edn` file:

   ```clj
   ;; shadow-cljs configuration
   {:source-paths
   ["src"]

   :builds
   {:lib {:target :node-library
           :output-to "dist/index.js"
           :exports {:citation citegen.processor.main/citation}}}}
   ```

   First watch:

   ```
   root@97db64e5dfa3:/workspaces/citegen# cd packages/csl-processor/
   root@97db64e5dfa3:/workspaces/citegen/packages/csl-processor# yarn shadow-cljs cljs-repl lib
   yarn run v1.17.3
   $ /workspaces/citegen/node_modules/.bin/shadow-cljs cljs-repl lib
   shadow-cljs - config: /workspaces/citegen/packages/csl-processor/shadow-cljs.edn  cli version: 2.8.52  node: v12.10.0
   shadow-cljs - socket connect failed, server process dead?
   shadow-cljs - updating dependencies
   ...
   shadow-cljs - dependencies updated
   shadow-cljs - server version: 2.8.52 running at http://localhost:9630
   shadow-cljs - nREPL server started on port 36017
   [0:0]~cljs.user=>
   ```

   Then in another terminal: (note the error message)

   ```
   root@97db64e5dfa3:/workspaces/citegen# cd packages/csl-processor/
   root@97db64e5dfa3:/workspaces/citegen/packages/csl-processor# yarn shadow-cljs cljs-repl lib
   yarn run v1.17.3
   $ /workspaces/citegen/node_modules/.bin/shadow-cljs cljs-repl lib
   shadow-cljs - config: /workspaces/citegen/packages/csl-processor/shadow-cljs.edn  cli version: 2.8.52  node: v12.10.0
   shadow-cljs - connected to server
   [1:1]~cljs.user=> (inc 41)
   No application has connected to the REPL server. Make sure your JS environment has loaded your compiled ClojureScript code.
   ```
2. With VS Code [Calva](http://shadow-cljs.org/):

   Given the same `shadow-cljs.edn` file as above:

   [image]

   When I try to manually load the namespace with `Calva: Load current namespace in REPL window`, I get the same error:

   > No application has connected to the REPL server. Make sure your JS environment has loaded your compiled ClojureScript code.

**Question:** How do I get to that perfect world?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to Thomas Heller I have managed to get this to work.

What I didn't realise was that I needed to run the build artefact once in order to connect to the REPL.

This will effectively get rid of this error:

> No application has connected to the REPL server. Make sure your JS environment has loaded your compiled ClojureScript code.

**Steps**

1. In VS Code open any ClojureScript file
2. Press <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> and select `Calva: Start a project REPL and connect (aka Jack-in)`
3. Wait until the REPL window opens
4. Only then, open a new terminal and require your build artefact so that a connect to the REPL is made. e.g. `node -e "require('./dist')"`
5. Open any ClojureScript file you want to evaluate in the REPL, press <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> and select `Calva: Load current namespace in the REPL window`

I have attached a screencast below. As you can see:

- The namespace in the CLJS REPL window isn't set to `undefined` anymore
- Any change to your ClojureScript file is both automatically recompiled and available in the REPL

[image]

Comment: This is a nice write-up. It would be a very good contribution to the Calva wiki. Maybe as the first content on a new page named "Using with shadow-cljs”, or something. Just sayn'.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest reading the manual section on [REPL Troubleshooting](https://shadow-cljs.github.io/docs/UsersGuide.html#repl-troubleshooting).

You most likely want to run `shadow-cljs node-repl`. This starts a REPL with a connected managed runtime. Otherwise you need something running node to load the code produced by `:node-library` as described in the manual.

You can do this manually if you like by running `node` and then `require("./dist/index.js")`. Once that is done the `cljs-repl` will be able to eval.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer triggered my "Aha" moment; I didn't realise that requiring the compiled Node.js module would connect to the REPL. I'll write up an answer with what worked for me.

Comment: For anyone's information, Calva gives you quick access to connect a `node-repl`. At Jack-in/connect, choose `node-repl` instead of the build id, when prompted about which REPL to connect to.